# Ellipsis inside button content Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

is it possible to get ellipsis inside button when content length increase the width of button.
I tried editing template but did get much success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have some options. If it's just at the instance, you can just plop your content in as `TextBlock` so something like;

```
<Button>
  <Button.Content>
     <TextBlock Text="Blah Blah Blah" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Or if you make a custom style template for `Button` you could replace the `ContentPresenter` in it with a `TextBlock` with it's content bound to the template like `Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"` and apply your TextTrimming directly to it. Except remember TextTrimming needs a boundary to invoke it, so your Button's may require like a set MaxWidth/Width or its parent panel will have to restrict its size to invoke the trimming.

Hope this helps, Cheers.

PS - This same concept can be used in WP, WPF, Silverlight, whatever really.